# How can I tell if my tile is ceramic or porcelain?

Tags: tile, drill, ceramic-tile, porcelain, drill-bit

I need to drill into some tile. How can I tell if it's ceramic or porcelain? I want to use the correct drill bit.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to participate. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: I'm not keen to write up a full answer at the moment, but this should help: https://www.wikihow.com/Tell-The-Difference-Between-Porcelain-and-Ceramic-Tiles

Comment: trick question: porcelain is a ceramic along with stoneware, earthenware, and terra cotta, in descending order of density.

Answer (score 4):

A diamond-tipped bit will drill through either material so just buy it.

Trying to save 50% on a carbide bit for ceramic tile is just not worth the risk of ruining potentially porcelain tile.

Comment: While good advice, this doesn't answer the question. Just buying it isn't always an option or the wise move.